# calling expect script inside a while loop of shell script

Tags: expect

I am trying to automate password-less ssh setup from master account to other slave accounts.I have a script named `AddSSH.ksh` which does this setup.When this script is run manually,it asks for same password same times,it basically copied keys using scp. All the slave accounts are saved in a file `env.txt`.So Now, I have a shell script(`run.ksh`) which reads the accounts from this file(`env.txt`) one by one and then uses `expect` script `auto_ssh.ksh` to handle the interaction and it enters the password accordingly.

**env.txt**

```
account1@machine1
account2@machine2
account3@machine3
account4@machine4
```

**run.ksh**:

```
#!/usr/bin/ksh

while read env
do

username=`echo $env | cut -d"@" -f1`;
hostname=`echo $env | cut -d"@" -f2`;
password='Unix_11'
ssh -n -o PasswordAuthentication=no ${env} ' ' 2>/dev/null
if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
        printf "\nConnection OK for : $env \n"
else
        expect auto_ssh.ksh $username $hostname $password
fi
done<env.txt
```

**auto_ssh.ksh**:

```
#!expect
set timeout 6
set user [lindex $argv 0]
set machine [lindex $argv 1]
set password [lindex $argv 2]
spawn AddSSH.ksh $user $machine
expect "password:"
send "$password\r";
expect "password:"
send "$password\r";
interact
```

If a run the script `auto_ssh.ksh` like

```
./auto_ssh.ksh account1 machine1 password
```

It runs fine but when I call it inside shell script,this expect script exits at the second password.when I ran the shell script in debug mode, I see that instead of sending the password the second time it moves to reading the next env from `env.txt` and exits.

This is the line of the output in debug mode where it fails.

```
account1@machine1's password: + read env
```

Answer (score 0):

Add `exp_internal 1` to the expect script for additional debugging. I suspect you might need to refine what you expect: `expect -re {password:\s*$}`

If you don't need to actually interact with addSSH.ksh, change `interact` to `expect eof`

Why does your expect script have a ".ksh" extension?